# Manage files and directories in browser

Tags: php, couch-cms

I'm using a PHP based CMS called Couch ([CouchCMS](http://www.couchcms.com/)).

The interface is pretty simple. It's easy to edit page content and that's basically it.

I'm now trying to add functionality. I want to add a tab called "files". This tab when activated is going to display all my files. For example it will show me my "images" folder and all the other files located in my website's folder.

Is it possible to somehow with PHP show all my directories on my web page and from there add and remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

But I think you can use jQuery + PHP libraries that do this for you: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

This is a php code used for the Silverstripe cms, don't know if it might work on your side.

```
<?php
/**
 * AssetAdmin is the 'file store' section of the CMS.
 * It provides an interface for manipulating the File and Folder objects in the system.
 * 
 * @package cms
 * @subpackage assets
 */
class AssetAdmin extends LeftAndMain implements PermissionProvider{

    private static $url_segment = 'assets';

    private static $url_rule = '/$Action/$ID';

    private static $menu_title = 'Files';

    private static $tree_class = 'Folder';

    /**
     * Amount of results showing on a single page.
     *
     * @config
     * @var int
     */
    private static $page_length = 15;

    /**
     * @config
     * @see Upload->allowedMaxFileSize
     * @var int
     */
    private static $allowed_max_file_size;

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'addfolder',
        'delete',
        'AddForm',
        'DeleteItemsForm',
        'SearchForm',
        'getsubtree',
        'movemarked',
        'removefile',
        'savefile',
        'deleteUnusedThumbnails' => 'ADMIN',
        'doSync',
        'filter',
    );

    /**
     * Return fake-ID "root" if no ID is found (needed to upload files into the root-folder)
     */
    public function currentPageID() {
        if(is_numeric($this->request->requestVar('ID')))    {
            return $this->request->requestVar('ID');
        } elseif (is_numeric($this->urlParams['ID'])) {
            return $this->urlParams['ID'];
        } elseif(Session::get("{$this->class}.currentPage")) {
            return Session::get("{$this->class}.currentPage");
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set up the controller, in particular, re-sync the File database with the assets folder./
     */
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        // Create base folder if it doesnt exist already
        if(!file_exists(ASSETS_PATH)) Filesystem::makeFolder(ASSETS_PATH);

        Requirements::javascript(CMS_DIR . "/javascript/AssetAdmin.js");
        Requirements::javascript(CMS_DIR . '/javascript/CMSMain.GridField.js');
        Requirements::add_i18n_javascript(CMS_DIR . '/javascript/lang', false, true);
        Requirements::css(CMS_DIR . "/css/screen.css");
        $frameworkDir = FRAMEWORK_DIR;
        Requirements::customScript(<<<JS
            _TREE_ICONS = {};
            _TREE_ICONS['Folder'] = {
                    fileIcon: '$frameworkDir/javascript/tree/images/page-closedfolder.gif',
                    openFolderIcon: '$frameworkDir/javascript/tree/images/page-openfolder.gif',
                    closedFolderIcon: '$frameworkDir/javascript/tree/images/page-closedfolder.gif'
            };
JS
        );

        CMSBatchActionHandler::register('delete', 'AssetAdmin_DeleteBatchAction', 'Folder');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the files and subfolders contained in the currently selected folder,
     * defaulting to the root node. Doubles as search results, if any search parameters
     * are set through {@link SearchForm()}.
     * 
     * @return SS_List
     */
    public function getList() {
        $folder = $this->currentPage();
        $context = $this->getSearchContext();
        // Overwrite name filter to search both Name and Title attributes
        $context->removeFilterByName('Name');
        $params = $this->request->requestVar('q');
        $list = $context->getResults($params);

        // Don't filter list when a detail view is requested,
        // to avoid edge cases where the filtered list wouldn't contain the requested
        // record due to faulty session state (current folder not always encoded in URL, see #7408).
        if(!$folder->ID
            && $this->request->requestVar('ID') === null
            && ($this->request->param('ID') == 'field')
        ) {
            return $list;
        }

        // Re-add previously removed "Name" filter as combined filter
        // TODO Replace with composite SearchFilter once that API exists
        if(!empty($params['Name'])) {
            $list = $list->filterAny(array(
                'Name:PartialMatch' => $params['Name'],
                'Title:PartialMatch' => $params['Name']
            ));
        }

        // Always show folders at the top       
        $list = $list->sort('(CASE WHEN "File"."ClassName" = \'Folder\' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), "Name"');

        // If a search is conducted, check for the "current folder" limitation.
        // Otherwise limit by the current folder as denoted by the URL.
        if(empty($params) || !empty($params['CurrentFolderOnly'])) {
            $list = $list->filter('ParentID', $folder->ID);
        }

        // Category filter
        if(!empty($params['AppCategory'])
            && !empty(File::config()->app_categories[$params['AppCategory']])
        ) {
            $exts = File::config()->app_categories[$params['AppCategory']];
            $list = $list->filter('Name:PartialMatch', $exts);
        }

        // Date filter
        if(!empty($params['CreatedFrom'])) {
            $fromDate = new DateField(null, null, $params['CreatedFrom']);
            $list = $list->filter("Created:GreaterThanOrEqual", $fromDate->dataValue().' 00:00:00');
        }
        if(!empty($params['CreatedTo'])) {
            $toDate = new DateField(null, null, $params['CreatedTo']);
            $list = $list->filter("Created:LessThanOrEqual", $toDate->dataValue().' 23:59:59');
        }

        return $list;
    }

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
        $folder = ($id && is_numeric($id)) ? DataObject::get_by_id('Folder', $id, false) : $this->currentPage();
        $fields = $form->Fields();
        $title = ($folder && $folder->exists()) ? $folder->Title : _t('AssetAdmin.FILES', 'Files');
        $fields->push(new HiddenField('ID', false, $folder ? $folder->ID : null));

        // File listing
        $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
            new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
            new GridFieldSortableHeader(),
            new GridFieldFilterHeader(),
            new GridFieldDataColumns(),
            new GridFieldPaginator(self::config()->page_length),
            new GridFieldEditButton(),
            new GridFieldDeleteAction(),
            new GridFieldDetailForm(),
            GridFieldLevelup::create($folder->ID)->setLinkSpec('admin/assets/show/%d')
        );

        $gridField = GridField::create('File', $title, $this->getList(), $gridFieldConfig);
        $columns = $gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns');
        $columns->setDisplayFields(array(
            'StripThumbnail' => '',
            // 'Parent.FileName' => 'Folder',
            'Title' => _t('File.Name'),
            'Created' => _t('AssetAdmin.CREATED', 'Date'),
            'Size' => _t('AssetAdmin.SIZE', 'Size'),
        ));
        $columns->setFieldCasting(array(
            'Created' => 'Date->Nice'
        ));
        $gridField->setAttribute(
            'data-url-folder-template', 
            Controller::join_links($this->Link('show'), '%s')
        );

        if($folder->canCreate()) {
            $uploadBtn = new LiteralField(
                'UploadButton', 
                sprintf(
                    '<a class="ss-ui-button ss-ui-action-constructive cms-panel-link" data-pjax-target="Content" data-icon="drive-upload" href="%s">%s</a>',
                    Controller::join_links(singleton('CMSFileAddController')->Link(), '?ID=' . $folder->ID),
                    _t('Folder.UploadFilesButton', 'Upload')
                )
            );  
        } else {
            $uploadBtn = null;
        }

        if(!$folder->hasMethod('canAddChildren') || ($folder->hasMethod('canAddChildren') && $folder->canAddChildren())) {
            // TODO Will most likely be replaced by GridField logic
            $addFolderBtn = new LiteralField(
                'AddFolderButton', 
                sprintf(
                    '<a class="ss-ui-button ss-ui-action-constructive cms-add-folder-link" data-icon="add" data-url="%s" href="%s">%s</a>',
                    Controller::join_links($this->Link('AddForm'), '?' . http_build_query(array(
                        'action_doAdd' => 1,
                        'ParentID' => $folder->ID,
                        'SecurityID' => $form->getSecurityToken()->getValue()
                    ))),
                    Controller::join_links($this->Link('addfolder'), '?ParentID=' . $folder->ID),
                    _t('Folder.AddFolderButton', 'Add folder')
                )
            );
        } else {
            $addFolderBtn = '';
        }

        if($folder->canEdit()) {
            $syncButton = new LiteralField(
                'SyncButton',
                sprintf(
                    '<a class="ss-ui-button ss-ui-action ui-button-text-icon-primary ss-ui-button-ajax" data-icon="arrow-circle-double" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>',
                    _t('AssetAdmin.FILESYSTEMSYNCTITLE', 'Update the CMS database entries of files on the filesystem. Useful when new files have been uploaded outside of the CMS, e.g. through FTP.'),
                    $this->Link('doSync'),
                    _t('AssetAdmin.FILESYSTEMSYNC','Sync files')
                )
            );
        } else {
            $syncButton = null;
        }

        // Move existing fields to a "details" tab, unless they've already been tabbed out through extensions.
        // Required to keep Folder->getCMSFields() simple and reuseable,
        // without any dependencies into AssetAdmin (e.g. useful for "add folder" views).
        if(!$fields->hasTabset()) {
            $tabs = new TabSet('Root', 
                $tabList = new Tab('ListView', _t('AssetAdmin.ListView', 'List View')),
                $tabTree = new Tab('TreeView', _t('AssetAdmin.TreeView', 'Tree View'))
            );
            $tabList->addExtraClass("content-listview cms-tabset-icon list");
            $tabTree->addExtraClass("content-treeview cms-tabset-icon tree");
            if($fields->Count() && $folder->exists()) {
                $tabs->push($tabDetails = new Tab('DetailsView', _t('AssetAdmin.DetailsView', 'Details')));
                $tabDetails->addExtraClass("content-galleryview cms-tabset-icon edit");
                foreach($fields as $field) {
                    $fields->removeByName($field->getName());
                    $tabDetails->push($field);
                }
            }
            $fields->push($tabs);
        }

        // we only add buttons if they're available. User might not have permission and therefore
        // the button shouldn't be available. Adding empty values into a ComposteField breaks template rendering.
        $actionButtonsComposite = CompositeField::create()->addExtraClass('cms-actions-row');
        if($uploadBtn) $actionButtonsComposite->push($uploadBtn);
        if($addFolderBtn) $actionButtonsComposite->push($addFolderBtn);
        if($syncButton) $actionButtonsComposite->push($syncButton);

        // List view
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.ListView', array(
            $actionsComposite = CompositeField::create(
                $actionButtonsComposite
            )->addExtraClass('cms-content-toolbar field'),
            $gridField
        ));

        $treeField = new LiteralField('Tree', '');
        // Tree view
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.TreeView', array(
            clone $actionsComposite,
            // TODO Replace with lazy loading on client to avoid performance hit of rendering potentially unused views
            new LiteralField(
                'Tree',
                FormField::create_tag(
                    'div', 
                    array(
                        'class' => 'cms-tree', 
                        'data-url-tree' => $this->Link('getsubtree'), 
                        'data-url-savetreenode' => $this->Link('savetreenode')
                    ),
                    $this->SiteTreeAsUL()
                )
            )
        ));

        // Move actions to "details" tab (they don't make sense on list/tree view)
        $actions = $form->Actions();
        $saveBtn = $actions->fieldByName('action_save');
        $deleteBtn = $actions->fieldByName('action_delete');
        $actions->removeByName('action_save');
        $actions->removeByName('action_delete');
        if(($saveBtn || $deleteBtn) && $fields->fieldByName('Root.DetailsView')) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab(
                'Root.DetailsView', 
                CompositeField::create($saveBtn,$deleteBtn)->addExtraClass('Actions')
            );
        }



        $fields->setForm($form);
        $form->setTemplate($this->getTemplatesWithSuffix('_EditForm'));
        // TODO Can't merge $FormAttributes in template at the moment
        $form->addExtraClass('cms-edit-form cms-panel-padded center ' . $this->BaseCSSClasses());
        $form->setAttribute('data-pjax-fragment', 'CurrentForm');
        $form->Fields()->findOrMakeTab('Root')->setTemplate('CMSTabSet');

        $this->extend('updateEditForm', $form);

        return $form;
    }

    public function addfolder($request) {
        $obj = $this->customise(array(
            'EditForm' => $this->AddForm()
        ));

        if($request->isAjax()) {
            // Rendering is handled by template, which will call EditForm() eventually
            $content = $obj->renderWith($this->getTemplatesWithSuffix('_Content'));
        } else {
            $content = $obj->renderWith($this->getViewer('show'));
        }

        return $content;
    }

    public function delete($data, $form) {
        $className = $this->stat('tree_class');

        $record = DataObject::get_by_id($className, Convert::raw2sql($data['ID']));
        if($record && !$record->canDelete()) return Security::permissionFailure();
        if(!$record || !$record->ID) throw new HTTPResponse_Exception("Bad record ID #" . (int)$data['ID'], 404);
        $parentID = $record->ParentID;
        $record->delete();
        $this->setCurrentPageID(null);

        $this->response->addHeader('X-Status', rawurlencode(_t('LeftAndMain.DELETED', 'Deleted.')));
        $this->response->addHeader('X-Pjax', 'Content');
        return $this->redirect(Controller::join_links($this->Link('show'), $parentID ? $parentID : 0));
    }

    /**
     * Get the search context
     *
     * @return SearchContext
     */
    public function getSearchContext() {
        $context = singleton('File')->getDefaultSearchContext();

        // Namespace fields, for easier detection if a search is present
        foreach($context->getFields() as $field) $field->setName(sprintf('q[%s]', $field->getName()));
        foreach($context->getFilters() as $filter) $filter->setFullName(sprintf('q[%s]', $filter->getFullName()));

        // Customize fields
        $context->addField(
            new HeaderField('q[Date]', _t('CMSSearch.FILTERDATEHEADING', 'Date'), 4)
        );
        $context->addField(
            DateField::create(
                'q[CreatedFrom]', 
                _t('CMSSearch.FILTERDATEFROM', 'From')
            )->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
        );
        $context->addField(
            DateField::create(
                'q[CreatedTo]',
                _t('CMSSearch.FILTERDATETO', 'To')
            )->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
        );
        $appCategories = array(
            'image' => _t('AssetAdmin.AppCategoryImage', 'Image'),
            'audio' => _t('AssetAdmin.AppCategoryAudio', 'Audio'),
            'mov' => _t('AssetAdmin.AppCategoryVideo', 'Video'),
            'flash' => _t('AssetAdmin.AppCategoryFlash', 'Flash', 'The fileformat'),
            'zip' => _t('AssetAdmin.AppCategoryArchive', 'Archive', 'A collection of files'),
            'doc' => _t('AssetAdmin.AppCategoryDocument', 'Document')
        );
        $context->addField(
            $typeDropdown = new DropdownField(
                'q[AppCategory]',
                _t('AssetAdmin.Filetype', 'File type'),
                $appCategories
            )
        );

        $typeDropdown->setEmptyString(' ');

        $context->addField(
            new CheckboxField('q[CurrentFolderOnly]', _t('AssetAdmin.CurrentFolderOnly', 'Limit to current folder?'))
        );
        $context->getFields()->removeByName('q[Title]');

        return $context;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a form for filtering of files and assets gridfield.
     * Result filtering takes place in {@link getList()}.
     *
     * @return Form
     * @see AssetAdmin.js
     */
    public function SearchForm() {
        $folder = $this->currentPage();
        $context = $this->getSearchContext();

        $fields = $context->getSearchFields();
        $actions = new FieldList(
            FormAction::create('doSearch',  _t('CMSMain_left_ss.APPLY_FILTER', 'Apply Filter'))
                ->addExtraClass('ss-ui-action-constructive'),
            Object::create('ResetFormAction', 'clear', _t('CMSMain_left_ss.RESET', 'Reset'))
        );

        $form = new Form($this, 'filter', $fields, $actions);
        $form->setFormMethod('GET');
        $form->setFormAction(Controller::join_links($this->Link('show'), $folder->ID));
        $form->addExtraClass('cms-search-form');
        $form->loadDataFrom($this->request->getVars());
        $form->disableSecurityToken();
        // This have to match data-name attribute on the gridfield so that the javascript selectors work
        $form->setAttribute('data-gridfield', 'File');
        return $form;
    }

    public function AddForm() {
        $folder = singleton('Folder');
        $form = CMSForm::create( 
            $this,
            'AddForm',
            new FieldList(
                new TextField("Name", _t('File.Name')),
                new HiddenField('ParentID', false, $this->request->getVar('ParentID'))
            ),
            new FieldList(
                FormAction::create('doAdd', _t('AssetAdmin_left_ss.GO','Go'))
                    ->addExtraClass('ss-ui-action-constructive')->setAttribute('data-icon', 'accept')
                    ->setTitle(_t('AssetAdmin.ActionAdd', 'Add folder'))
            )
        )->setHTMLID('Form_AddForm');
        $form->setResponseNegotiator($this->getResponseNegotiator());
        $form->setTemplate($this->getTemplatesWithSuffix('_EditForm'));
        // TODO Can't merge $FormAttributes in template at the moment
        $form->addExtraClass('add-form cms-add-form cms-edit-form cms-panel-padded center ' . $this->BaseCSSClasses());

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new group and return its details suitable for ajax.
     * 
     * @todo Move logic into Folder class, and use LeftAndMain->doAdd() default implementation.
     */
    public function doAdd($data, $form) {
        $class = $this->stat('tree_class');

        // check create permissions
        if(!singleton($class)->canCreate()) return Security::permissionFailure($this);

        // check addchildren permissions
        if(
            singleton($class)->hasExtension('Hierarchy') 
            && isset($data['ParentID'])
            && is_numeric($data['ParentID'])
            && $data['ParentID']
        ) {
            $parentRecord = DataObject::get_by_id($class, $data['ParentID']);
            if(
                $parentRecord->hasMethod('canAddChildren') 
                && !$parentRecord->canAddChildren()
            ) return Security::permissionFailure($this);
        } else {
            $parentRecord = null;
        }

        $parent = (isset($data['ParentID']) && is_numeric($data['ParentID'])) ? (int)$data['ParentID'] : 0;
        $name = (isset($data['Name'])) ? basename($data['Name']) : _t('AssetAdmin.NEWFOLDER',"NewFolder");
        if(!$parentRecord || !$parentRecord->ID) $parent = 0;

        // Get the folder to be created     
        if($parentRecord && $parentRecord->ID) $filename = $parentRecord->FullPath . $name;
        else $filename = ASSETS_PATH . '/' . $name;

        // Actually create
        if(!file_exists(ASSETS_PATH)) {
            mkdir(ASSETS_PATH);
        }

        $record = new Folder();
        $record->ParentID = $parent;
        $record->Name = $record->Title = basename($filename);

        // Ensure uniqueness        
        $i = 2;
        $baseFilename = substr($record->Filename, 0, -1) . '-';
        while(file_exists($record->FullPath)) {
            $record->Filename = $baseFilename . $i . '/';
            $i++;
        }

        $record->Name = $record->Title = basename($record->Filename);
        $record->write();

        mkdir($record->FullPath);
        chmod($record->FullPath, Filesystem::config()->file_create_mask);

        if($parentRecord) {
            return $this->redirect(Controller::join_links($this->Link('show'), $parentRecord->ID));
        } else {
            return $this->redirect($this->Link());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom currentPage() method to handle opening the 'root' folder
     */
    public function currentPage() {
        $id = $this->currentPageID();
        if($id && is_numeric($id) && $id > 0) {
            $folder = DataObject::get_by_id('Folder', $id);
            if($folder && $folder->exists()) {
                return $folder;
            }
        }
        $this->setCurrentPageID(null);
        return new Folder();
    }

    public function getSiteTreeFor($className, $rootID = null, $childrenMethod = null, $numChildrenMethod = null, $filterFunction = null, $minNodeCount = 30) {
        if (!$childrenMethod) $childrenMethod = 'ChildFolders';
        if (!$numChildrenMethod) $numChildrenMethod = 'numChildFolders';
        return parent::getSiteTreeFor($className, $rootID, $childrenMethod, $numChildrenMethod, $filterFunction, $minNodeCount);
    }

    public function getCMSTreeTitle() {
        return Director::absoluteBaseURL() . "assets";
    }

    public function SiteTreeAsUL() {
        return $this->getSiteTreeFor($this->stat('tree_class'), null, 'ChildFolders', 'numChildFolders');
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    // Data saving handlers

    /**
     * Can be queried with an ajax request to trigger the filesystem sync. It returns a FormResponse status message
     * to display in the CMS
     */
    public function doSync() {
        $message = Filesystem::sync();
        $this->response->addHeader('X-Status', rawurlencode($message));

        return;
    }

    /**
     * #################################
     *        Garbage collection.
     * #################################
    */

    /**
     * Removes all unused thumbnails from the file store
     * and returns the status of the process to the user.
     */
    public function deleteunusedthumbnails($request) {
        // Protect against CSRF on destructive action
        if(!SecurityToken::inst()->checkRequest($request)) return $this->httpError(400);

        $count = 0;
        $thumbnails = $this->getUnusedThumbnails();

        if($thumbnails) {
            foreach($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
                unlink(ASSETS_PATH . "/" . $thumbnail);
                $count++;
            }
        }

        $message = _t(
            'AssetAdmin.THUMBSDELETED', 
            '{count} unused thumbnails have been deleted', 
            array('count' => $count)
        );
        $this->response->addHeader('X-Status', rawurlencode($message));
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Creates array containg all unused thumbnails.
     * 
     * Array is created in three steps:
     *     1. Scan assets folder and retrieve all thumbnails
     *     2. Scan all HTMLField in system and retrieve thumbnails from them.
     *     3. Count difference between two sets (array_diff)
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    private function getUnusedThumbnails() {
        $allThumbnails = array();
        $usedThumbnails = array();
        $dirIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(ASSETS_PATH));
        $classes = ClassInfo::subclassesFor('SiteTree');

        if($dirIterator) {
            foreach($dirIterator as $file) {
                if($file->isFile()) {
                    if(strpos($file->getPathname(), '_resampled') !== false) {
                        $pathInfo = pathinfo($file->getPathname());
                        if(in_array(strtolower($pathInfo['extension']), array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png', 'gif'))) {
                            $path = str_replace('\\','/', $file->getPathname());
                            $allThumbnails[] = substr($path, strpos($path, '/assets/') + 8);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if($classes) {
            foreach($classes as $className) {
                $SNG_class = singleton($className);
                $objects = DataObject::get($className);

                if($objects !== NULL) {
                    foreach($objects as $object) {
                        foreach($SNG_class->db() as $fieldName => $fieldType) {
                            if($fieldType == 'HTMLText') {
                                $url1 = HTTP::findByTagAndAttribute($object->$fieldName,array('img' => 'src'));

                                if($url1 != NULL) {
                                    $usedThumbnails[] = substr($url1[0], strpos($url1[0], '/assets/') + 8);
                                }

                                if($object->latestPublished > 0) {
                                    $object = Versioned::get_latest_version($className, $object->ID);
                                    $url2 = HTTP::findByTagAndAttribute($object->$fieldName, array('img' => 'src'));

                                    if($url2 != NULL) {
                                        $usedThumbnails[] = substr($url2[0], strpos($url2[0], '/assets/') + 8);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return array_diff($allThumbnails, $usedThumbnails);
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $unlinked
     * @return ArrayList
     */
    public function Breadcrumbs($unlinked = false) {
        $items = parent::Breadcrumbs($unlinked);

        // The root element should explicitly point to the root node.
        // Uses session state for current record otherwise.
        $items[0]->Link = Controller::join_links(singleton('AssetAdmin')->Link('show'), 0);

        // If a search is in progress, don't show the path
        if($this->request->requestVar('q')) {
            $items = $items->limit(1);
            $items->push(new ArrayData(array(
                'Title' => _t('LeftAndMain.SearchResults', 'Search Results'),
                'Link' => Controller::join_links($this->Link(), '?' . http_build_query(array('q' => $this->request->requestVar('q'))))
            )));
        }

        // If we're adding a folder, note that in breadcrumbs as well
        if($this->request->param('Action') == 'addfolder') {
            $items->push(new ArrayData(array(
                'Title' => _t('Folder.AddFolderButton', 'Add folder'),
                'Link' => false
            )));
        }

        return $items;
    }

    public function providePermissions() {
        $title = _t("AssetAdmin.MENUTITLE", LeftAndMain::menu_title_for_class($this->class));
        return array(
            "CMS_ACCESS_AssetAdmin" => array(
                'name' => _t('CMSMain.ACCESS', "Access to '{title}' section", array('title' => $title)),
                'category' => _t('Permission.CMS_ACCESS_CATEGORY', 'CMS Access')
            )
        );
    }

}
/**
 * Delete multiple {@link Folder} records (and the associated filesystem nodes).
 * Usually used through the {@link AssetAdmin} interface.
 * 
 * @package cms
 * @subpackage batchactions
 */
class AssetAdmin_DeleteBatchAction extends CMSBatchAction {
    public function getActionTitle() {
        // _t('AssetAdmin_left_ss.SELECTTODEL','Select the folders that you want to delete and then click the button below')
        return _t('AssetAdmin_DeleteBatchAction.TITLE', 'Delete folders');
    }

    public function run(SS_List $records) {
        $status = array(
            'modified'=>array(),
            'deleted'=>array()
        );

        foreach($records as $record) {
            $id = $record->ID;

            // Perform the action
            if($record->canDelete()) $record->delete();

            $status['deleted'][$id] = array();

            $record->destroy();
            unset($record);
        }

        return Convert::raw2json($status);
    }
}
```